# Twitter API - Verify credentials

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to get user ID and user name from Twitter.
What the application should do is get the necessary info from a Twitter account (sended by the website of the application), get the userID and username from the account, check if that account already exists in database, and allow the user use the application.

My problem is that I'm trying to understand the methods and the url's to get the info and from the Twitter API website or other forums I get more confused about what data to receive from the website and what to do with that data to get the info I need.

If it helps, I'm developing the application in Java and I only want to get the information trough url's (e.g. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json) and not from the Twitter4j library or other libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you want to use Twitter4J? Libraries are there so you don't have to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: @BenjaminDale Okay, so I'm using the Twitter4J, now I still having a problem, I'm gonna receive an "Access Token" and I need to get user details. How should I do it?
I already have the "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret".

Comment: @Auhmaan are you able to get twitter access token, using twitter4j??

Comment: You have to setup up an application on dev.twitter.com to get your keys

Comment: Thanks for all of your support and help. :) I make a way to get the data.